# How to delete all indexed documents in an index core in Solr after schema change

Tags: solr, indexing

I created and populated a new custom index. Since then I have changed my schema, but repopulating the schema and reindexing doesn't seem to actually update the number of documents or the indexed fields.

How do I clear out the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I had to do was visit this URL:

`https://solr:####/solr/name_of_index_core/update?commit=true&stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>`

Then I had to:

- Restart the solr service
- Restart Sitecore
- Repopulate schema
- Reindex

Though there might be some extra unnecessary steps in there, the amount of documents and indexed fields now appear as expected.